# Receiving UDP packets in a loop crashes linux kernel

Tags: c, loops, linux-kernel, network-programming, udp

I've modified UDP code in the linux kernel to implement send and receive buffers to handle out of order delivery of packets. When In the new code, whenever I try to deliver multiple packets to the socket from the receive buffer, I get a kernel crash. My code snippet:

```
while(!skb_queue_empty(&sk->sk_receive_queue)){
    skb = skb_peek(&sk->sk_receive_queue);
    qb = QUIC_SKB_CB(skb);

    //Check if this is the packet to be received
    if(qb->sequence != qp->first_rcv){
        printk("First packet in queue not yet received\nFirst packet seq %u\nExpected packet seq %u\n", qb->sequence, qp->first_rcv);
        //break;
        goto drop;
    }

    skb_unlink(skb, &sk->sk_receive_queue);
    if (sk_rcvqueues_full(sk, skb, sk->sk_rcvbuf))
        goto drop;


    rc = 0;

    ipv4_pktinfo_prepare(sk, skb);
    bh_lock_sock(sk);
    if (!sock_owned_by_user(sk))
        rc = __udp_queue_rcv_skb(sk, skb);
    else if (sk_add_backlog(sk, skb, sk->sk_rcvbuf)) {
        bh_unlock_sock(sk);
        goto drop;
    }
    bh_unlock_sock(sk);
    printk("Packets left in read buffer = %u\n", skb_queue_len(&sk->sk_receive_queue));
}

return rc;
```

However, **when I remove the while loop** from the code, the code runs fine, though I only manage to send one packet from the buffer. Also, the crash happens after `bh_lock_sock(sk)`, i.e. while the packet is being delivered to the socket. I figured this out by commenting the lines between locking and unlocking the socket.

What could possibly be going wrong with the loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was using `sk->sk_receive_queue` as the receive buffer, assuming UDP doesn't really use it. So when the function `__udp_queue_rcv_skb` was called, it'll use the list `sk->sk_receive_queue` and hence interfere with the queue I'd already populated.

I just defined another receive buffer in the `struct udp_opt` and I'm using it now.